# Delphi - Get combinations from multiple sets

Tags: delphi, set, combinations

Using: Delphi 10.2 Tokyo

Please link me to an algorithm or code to get all possible combinations of values from multiple sets, with one value per set. The number of sets is not known in advance, nor the number of values in each set.

Example:

```
1. (1, 2, 3) (A, B)
Desired result: 
1 A
1 B
2 A
2 B
3 A
3 B

2. (1, 2, 3, 4) (A, B) (X, Y, Z)
Desired result: 
1 A X
1 A Y
1 A Z
2 A X
2 A Y
2 A Z
3 A X
3 A Y
3 A Z
4 A X
4 A Y
4 A Z
1 B X
1 B Y
1 B Z
2 B X
2 B Y
2 B Z
3 B X
3 B Y
3 B Z
4 B X
4 B Y
4 B Z
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are basically looking for the n-ary Cartesian product of sets.

Comment: Notice that this task would be trivial if the number of sets (factors) was known in advance. Hence, your problem can be solved if you only find a way to *index* the outputs and find a way to go from index N to index N + 1. (You may actually get some inspiration from the Arabic number system: After 579 comes 580.)

Comment: The number of sets is not known in advance. The Delphi program I'm writing is parsing an XML file in order to create a CSV file of a particular format. You are correct, it the number of sets was known, this would be easy. Any suggestion or link to an algo or code for this problem?

Comment: Let the sets be S_i, i = 1..N and suppose the elements of S_i are (a_i_k), k = 1..N_i. Then each element in the n-ary Cartesian product gets an index induced by the indices of the sets and their elements, and to go from one index X to the next, X + 1, you follow the same rules as for Arabic numbers.

Comment: For example: {1, 2, 3} × {A, B} × {a, b, c}. Start with indices 1, 1, and 1: (1, A, a). Then, increase the index by one: 1, 1, 2: (1, A, b). Then 1, 1, 3: (1, A, c). But then the next would be 1, 1, 4, but there isn't any 4th element in {a, b, c}. So instead you let the last "digit" go back to its lowest value and increase the value of the next to last digit: 1, 2, 1: (1, B, a). Then 1, 2, 2: (1, B, b). then (1, 2, 3): (1, B, c). Then the next index would be (1, 2, 4), but there isn't any 4th element in {a, b, c}, so instead we take (1, 3, 1): (1, C, a). Then (1, 3, 2): (1, C, b) and so on.

Comment: This is exactly like 46, 47, 48, 49, **50**, 51, 52, right?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I got your gist. I have to work on the code for this now. If I get working code, I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Look in help for "Iteration Over Containers Using For statements"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursive and iterative generation (with storage and without storage) of cartesian product of 2d array A elements

```
var
  A: array of array of Integer;
  B: array of array of Integer;
  i, j: Integer;
  s: string;
  NN: Integer;

  procedure CartesianRec(From: Integer; cs: string);
  var
    j: integer;
  begin
    if From = Length(A) then
      Memo1.Lines.Add(cs)
    else
      for j := 0 to High(A[From]) do
        CartesianRec(From + 1, cs + IntToStr(A[From, j]) + ' ');
  end;

  procedure CartesianIter;
  var
    i, j, k, l, c, N, M: Integer;
  begin
    NN := 1;
    for k := 0 to High(A) do
      NN := NN * Length(A[k]);
    SetLength(B, NN, Length(A));
    N := NN;
    M := 1;
    for k := 0 to High(A) do begin
      N := N div Length(A[k]);
      c := 0;
      for l := 0 to M - 1 do
        for i := 0 to High(A[k]) do
          for j := 0 to N - 1 do begin
            B[c, k] := A[k, i];
            Inc(c);
          end;
      M := M * Length(A[k]);
    end;
  end;

  procedure CartesianOnline;
  var
    i, j, k, l, c, N, M, dimA: Integer;
    s: string;
  begin
    NN := 1;
    dimA := Length(A);
    //SetLength(CartProduct, dimA);
    for k := 0 to dimA - 1 do
      NN := NN * Length(A[k]);
    for i := 0 to NN - 1 do begin
      j := i;
      s := '';
      for k := dimA - 1 downto 0 do begin
        l := j mod Length(A[k]);
        s := IntToStr(A[k][l]) + ' ' + s;
        //we can also put CartProduct[k] := A[k][l];
        j := j div Length(A[k]);
      end;
      Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
      //or use CartProduct
    end;
  end;

  begin
  nn := 1;
  SetLength(A, 3);
  for i := 0 to High(A) do begin
    SetLength(A[i], 5 - i);
    s := '';
    for j := 0 to High(A[i]) do begin
      A[i, j] := nn;
      Inc(nn);
      s := s + IntToStr(A[i, j]) + ' ';
    end;
    Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
  end;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('------');
  CartesianRec(0, '');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('------');
  CartesianIter;
  for i := 0 to NN - 1 do begin
    s := '';
    for j := 0 to High(A) do
      s := s + IntToStr(B[i, j]) + ' ';
    Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
  end;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('------');
  CartesianOnline;
```

A:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 
10 11 12
```

Result:

```
1 6 10 
1 6 11 
1 6 12 
1 7 10 
1 7 11 
1 7 12 
1 8 10 
1 8 11 
1 8 12 
1 9 10 
1 9 11 
1 9 12 
2 6 10 
2 6 11 
...
5 8 12 
5 9 10 
5 9 11 
5 9 12
```

Comment: @Steve F Is my answer unclear?

Comment: It was clear. I just wanted to write my own algorithm (which I finally did - see my answer) before accepting this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used TLists and Integer arrays and managed to solve the problem. Here is my code:

```
uses Classes, SysUtils, Generics.Collections;

type
  TIntArray = array of integer;

  TIntArrayList = TList<TIntArray>;

  TCartesianProduct = class
  private
    FSetList: TIntArrayList;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure AddSet(ASet: TIntArray);
    procedure GetCombinations(var AIntArrayList: TIntArrayList);
  end;

implementation

{ TCartesianProduct }

constructor TCartesianProduct.Create;
begin
  FSetList := TIntArrayList.Create;
end;

destructor TCartesianProduct.Destroy;
begin
  FSetList.Free;
end;

procedure TCartesianProduct.AddSet(ASet: TIntArray);
begin
  FSetList.Add(ASet);
end;

procedure TCartesianProduct.GetCombinations(var AIntArrayList: TIntArrayList);
var
  WorkList, OuputList: TIntArrayList;
  r: TIntArray;
  n, c, l: integer;
  f: Boolean;
begin

  WorkList := TIntArrayList.Create; // Length of each set array, and current iteration index
  OuputList := TIntArrayList.Create;
  try
    n := FSetList.Count;

    for c := 0 to n - 1 do
      WorkList.Add([Length(FSetList[c]), 0]);

    while ((WorkList[0][1] < WorkList[0][0])) do
    begin

      SetLength(r, n); // result array length is the number of sets

      for c := 0 to FSetList.Count - 1 do
      begin
        r[c] := FSetList[c][WorkList[c][1]];
      end;

      Inc(WorkList[n - 1][1]); // last work list item (set)
      if (WorkList[n - 1][1] = WorkList[n - 1][0]) and (n - 1 <> 0) then // if it equal the length of the set
      begin
        WorkList[n - 1][1] := 0; // then reset it back to zero

        l := n - 1; // make pointer point to previous item up
        f := false;
        repeat
          Dec(l);

          if (l >= 0) then
          begin
            Inc(WorkList[l][1]); // increase index in previous item
            if (l <> 0) and (WorkList[l][1] = WorkList[l][0]) then
            begin
              WorkList[l][1] := 0; // If that items pointer points to the last item, reset it to zero
            end
            else
              f := true;
          end
          else
            f := true;

        until f;

      end;

      OuputList.Add(r);
    end;

    AIntArrayList.Clear;
    for c := 0 to OuputList.Count - 1 do
      AIntArrayList.Add(OuputList[c]);

  finally
    OuputList.Free;
    WorkList.Free;
  end;

end;
```

Test it with this code:

```
procedure TfmMain.btTestClick(Sender: TObject);
 var
 intset1, intset2, intset3: TIntArray;
 outsetlist: TIntArrayList;
 CP: TCartesianProduct;
 c, d: Integer;
 l: string;
begin
   SetLength(intset2, 4);
   SetLength(intset3, 4);
  
   intset2[0] := 105;
   intset2[1] := 106;
   intset2[2] := 107;
   intset2[3] := 108;
  
   intset3[0] := 109;
   intset3[1] := 110;
   intset3[2] := 111;
   intset3[3] := 112;
  
   outsetlist := TIntArrayList.Create;
   CP := TCartesianProduct.Create;
   try
   CP.AddSet(intset2);
   CP.AddSet(intset3);
  
   CP.GetCombinations(outsetlist);
  
   ListBox1.Clear;
  
   for c := 0 to outsetlist.Count - 1 do
   begin
   l := '';
   for d := 0 to high(outsetlist[c]) do
   l := l + Format('%d ', [outsetlist[c][d]]);
  
   ListBox1.Items.Add(l);
   end;
  
   finally
   CP.Free;
   outsetlist.Free;
   end;
end;
```